# Memory problem with basic UITableView when scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, uitableview

I have a very simple UITableView that has 3 sections, and 3 rows per section.

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITableView delegate methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tblView 
{ 
    if (tblView == self.tableView) {
        return 3;
    }
    else {
        return 1; 
    }
}
```

Everything shows up fine, but as soon as I scroll my application crashes and my debugger tells me:

***** -[ProfileViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5ae61b0**

I'm not exactly sure what I am doing wrong.

EDIT:
This is how I am displaying the ProfileViewController:

```
ProfileViewController* profileView = [[ProfileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProfileViewController" bundle:nil];
    profileView.user_name = username;
    profileView.message_source = messageSource;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:profileView animated:YES];
    [profileView release];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your `ProfileViewController` instance is getting deallocated somehow. Make sure you're not calling its `-autorelease` after creating it.

Comment: I have updated my code to show how I display my ProfileViewController. Do you see anything wrong?

Comment: I changed my NIB to contain a ViewController and a TableView instead of a TableViewController. It seemed to do the trick. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems right. Your bug might be in your model or in the cell configuration. Turn on [zombie support](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2004/tn2124.html#SECOBJECTIVEC) for search this kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

something that helped me a similar problem was realizing the following: you may need to retain a table view controller by setting it up as an IBOutlet if it is a subview of another view - i.e. the parent must, in some way, be retaining the child.

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of using**

cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

**please use**

cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

**And change your implementation code as follow:**

Don't use the below code in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method. Instead use in "didSelectRowAtIndex" method.

**In header(.h) file:**

ProfileViewController* profileView;

**In implementation (.m) file:**

if(profileView==nil)
   profileView = [[ProfileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProfileViewController" bundle:nil];
    profileView.user_name = username;
    profileView.message_source = messageSource;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:profileView animated:YES];